# ReactJS looping image source

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of image link. If I loop it inside `src` I only get first image. I have tried both `map()` and `for loop`. Both of them showing first image only.

```
for (let i = 0; i < screenshotList.length; i++) {
            return (
                <>
                    <img
                        src={screenshotList[i]}
                        width={60}
                        height={60}
                        style={{ marginTop: 10, marginLeft: 10 }}
                    />
                </>
            )
        }
```

I also tried with map function

```
screenshotList.map(value=>{
  console.log(value)
  return <img src={value} />
})
```

This also display first image only. How to fix it?

Comment: Can you show `screenshotList` data ?

Comment: That is from api fetch. console is printing value. also screenshot.length is printing the value

Comment: console.log(value) in map function is logging something ?

Comment: yes @samairali it is logging the image url for all screenshot

Comment: Can you post the result of `console.log(screenshotList)`

Comment: Solved. refer the accepted answer. Thanks for spending your valuable time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using return in `for` loop will return the function.

Try this.

```
let imageList = screenshotList.map((value, index)=>{
  console.log(value)
  return <img src={value} key={index} />
})
```

Use `imageList` in your render or in your function component return

eg:  `<div> {imageList} </div>`